SQLAlchemy relationship with models in separate files
Can someone tell me how to use SQLAlchemy relationship if each model is in a separate file? Example:
# ./models/user.py
class UserModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    characters: Mapped[list['CharacterModel']] = relationship(back_populates='user')

# ./models/character.py
class CharacterModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'characters'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey('users.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    characters: Mapped['UserModel'] = relationship(back_populates='characters')

# ./models/__init__.py
from . import user, character

Error when creating a user:
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper Mapper[UserModel(users)], expression 'CharacterModel' failed to locate a name ('CharacterModel'). If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the <class 'python.database.models.user.UserModel'> class after both dependent classes have been defined.

I can't find information anywhere, and in the use cases the models are always in the same file. I will be grateful for any information.

I found a solution, probably the only correct one. Everything is the same as in the code above, but at the end imports are added with the comment # noqa: E402 and add import from __future__ import annotations.
# ./models/user.py
from __future__ import annotations

class UserModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    characters: Mapped[list['CharacterModel']] = relationship(back_populates='user')

from .character import CharacterModel # noqa: E402


# ./models/character.py
from __future__ import annotations

class CharacterModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'characters'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey('users.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    characters: Mapped['UserModel'] = relationship(back_populates='characters')

from .user import UserModel # noqa: E402


# ./models/__init__.py
from . import user, character


Do you use the same Base object in both models?
There are 2 common mistakes that may cause problems here:

Creating new Base object in every module. Actually, it should be one object
Not importing some modules with models. You should import all modules containing your models, so that Base object knows about these models

Create file database.py:
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

Then import and use this Base object everywhere:
user.py
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped, mapped_column, relationship
from database import Base

class UserModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    characters: Mapped[list['CharacterModel']] = relationship(back_populates='user')

character.py
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped, mapped_column, relationship
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from database import Base

class CharacterModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'characters'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey('users.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    characters: Mapped['UserModel'] = relationship(back_populates='characters')


main.py

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from database import Base


# Import all modules with models!
import user
import character


engine = create_engine("sqlite://")

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

with Session(engine) as session:
    user_1 = user.UserModel()

    character_1 = character.CharacterModel(user=user_1)
    session.add(character_1)
    session.commit()
    session.refresh(character_1)

    print(f"{character_1.id=}, {character_1.user.id=}")


Yes, I am using the same Base object everywhere. The error occurs because of splitting the models in different files, SQLAlchemy can't find the CharacterModel model in the user.py file because that model is not imported there. But if I try to import the models, a cyclic import error occurs.

I just added full code example that works for me
